# can xpath search a child node and return a different node?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am able to isolate the "acronym" child node from the following

```
<tr id="PRO_0000155160">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cart-item" onclick="addOrAppendCart('P19614_1-66_', 'section_features')" id="checkbox_P19614_1-66_" />
  </td>
  <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <acronym title="Extent of a polypeptide chain in the mature protein." onclick="dialog('chain'); Event.stop(event || window.event); return false" onmousedown="Event.stop(event || window.event);">Chain</acronym>
  </td>
  <td class="numeric">
    <a href="/blast/?about=P19614[1-66]">1 – 66</a>
  </td>
  <td class="numeric">66</td>
  <td>Type-3 ice-structuring protein HPLC 12</td>
  <td style="text-align:center" class="ft-sequence">
    <table class="sequence" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='../blast/?about=P19614[1-66]'" title="Length: 66">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;" class="feature chain"> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span style="font-size: small;">PRO_0000155160</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

by doing:

```
//tr[contains(@id, '_')]//acronym[contains(@onclick,'chain')]
```

however I would like to return the either the "input" node above it (line 3) or the "href" node below it (line 9).

Normally I would write an xpath query that directly pulls out either the input or href nodes, however it is essential that the acronym node fills a certain criteria for my problem - namely containing the word "chain" in the onclick attribute.

Doing this ensures I have the correct "tr" root node (there are multiple tr's in the main xml file), however as I mentioned - I need either the input or href nodes of that particular tr root node.

Is this possible? I have tried appending ../ to the end of the query, but this doesn't work.

Comment: What about //input[//tr[contains(@id, '_')]//acronym[contains(@onclick,'chain')]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"above" is misleading you. "preceding" would have gotten you closer.

Spell out in detail exactly what you're trying to do. From the selected `acronym`, you want the nearest preceding `<input>` element, so add `/preceding::input[1]` to the end of your path. (The `[1]` is needed because otherwise you will match all `<input>` elements earlier in the document.

Similarly, use the `following::` axis to look later in the document with no structural constraints.

(Or you could be more explicit about exactly where the desired node is located relative to the one you've found, which would be more robust if the document structure isn't always as simple as shown here, and which could improve performance. But that's something you need to design based on knowing exactly what to expect in your input documents.)